# s3 list objects return null with sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a lambda function with has a role with Admin access. I have a S3 bucket and I want to test listing of its contents. Here is the code

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  var params = { Bucket: 'test-bucket-mine' };
  let result = await s3.listObjectsV2(params);
  console.log(result);
};
```

However, the console log looks like the following.

```
Response:
null
```

I am testing using lambda test with basic event. Please let me know where I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are awaiting the request object. The request is never being fired. Try:

```
let result = await s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise();
```

This will start the request and return a promise that resolves when the request completes. You will then await the result of that promise.